# FromDateTime value set to NULL even after selecting the date and time in DateTimePickerFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

I have added 2 datepickers one to take the starting date and time, and other to obtain to date and time.

at the time once I have entered date and time via datepicker for from time its diplaying that, but once I give To time and send this to other function , the value of fromDateTime changed to null, and ToDateTime value carry as it is,

how to store both from and to date time values?
Here below find my code

```
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: LimitedBox(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[     
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 27.0,
                      vertical: 5.0,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        DateTimePickerFormField(
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(2019),
                          lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                          inputType: InputType.both,
                          format: DateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mma"),
                          editable: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'From Date',
                              hasFloatingPlaceholder: false),
                          onChanged: (dt1) {
                              fromDatePicker = dt1;
                              radioSelected = null;
                            // print('Selected date: $fromDatePicker');
                          },
                        ),
                        DateTimePickerFormField(
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(2019),
                          lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                          inputType: InputType.both,
                          format: DateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mma"),
                          editable: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'To Date', hasFloatingPlaceholder: false),
                          //  initialValue: DateTime.now(),
                          onChanged: (dt) {
                            toDatePicker = dt;
                            radioSelected = null;
                            print('Selected date: $fromDatePicker : $toDatePicker');
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //  print("from Date: $fromDatePicker");
                        widget.parentAction(generateUserAction(widget.siSelected,
                            widget.timeSelected, fromDatePicker, toDatePicker));
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text('GO'),
                    ),
],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the whole Page, because probably this is a state problem.